# Why this strange sorting of dnf package result list?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

This might be the most useless question of the decade; however, it intrigued me, so I thought it might be worth sharing.

According to the manpage, `dnf search <something>` orders the list of results from the most relevant to the least.

On my Fedora 23 the result of `dnf search yum` is almost neatly ordered by length of package name + description:

```
[dr01@linuxbox ~]$ dnf search yum
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:06:14 ago on Fri Jan  8 14:03:49 2016.
================================================================================================ N/S Matched: yum =================================================================================================
yum.noarch : RPM package installer/updater/manager
yum-langpacks.noarch : Langpacks plugin for yum
yum-rhn-plugin.noarch : Spacewalk support for yum
yumdaemon.noarch : DBus daemon for yum package actions
yum-plugin-copr.noarch : Yum plugin to add copr command
yum-updateonboot.noarch : Run yum update on system boot
yum-axelget.noarch : Download accelerator plug-in for Yum
yum-metadata-parser.x86_64 : A fast metadata parser for yum
yumex.noarch : Yum Extender graphical package management tool
yum-plugin-keys.noarch : Yum plugin to deal with signing keys
yum-dellsysid.x86_64 : YUM plugin to retrieve the Dell System ID
yum-plugin-aliases.noarch : Yum plugin to enable aliases filters
yum-utils.noarch : Utilities based around the yum package manager
yumex-dnf.noarch : Yum Extender graphical package management tool
yum-plugin-ovl.noarch : Yum plugin to work around overlayfs issues
yum-plugin-tmprepo.noarch : Yum plugin to add temporary repositories
yum-plugin-list-data.noarch : Yum plugin to list aggregate package data
yum-plugin-verify.noarch : Yum plugin to add verify command, and options
perl-YUM-RepoQuery.noarch : Query a YUM repository for package information
yum-cron-daily.noarch : Files needed to run yum updates as a daily cron job
yum-plugin-tsflags.noarch : Yum plugin to add tsflags by a commandline option
yum-cron-hourly.noarch : Files needed to run yum updates as an hourly cron job
yum-plugin-filter-data.noarch : Yum plugin to list filter based on package data
yum-plugin-ps.noarch : Yum plugin to look at processes, with respect to packages
yum-cron-security.noarch : Files needed to run security yum updates as once a day
yum-plugin-puppetverify.noarch : Yum plugin to add puppet checksums to verify data
yum-plugin-show-leaves.noarch : Yum plugin which shows newly installed leaf packages
yum-plugin-versionlock.noarch : Yum plugin to lock specified packages from being updated
python-yumdaemon.noarch : Python 2 api for communicating with the yum-daemon DBus service
yum-plugin-protectbase.noarch : Yum plugin to protect packages from certain repositories.
python3-yumdaemon.noarch : Python 3 api for communicating with the yum-daemon DBus service
yum-plugin-refresh-updatesd.noarch : Tell yum-updatesd to check for updates when yum exits
dnf-yum.noarch : As a Yum CLI compatibility layer, supplies /usr/bin/yum redirecting to DNF.
yum-plugin-changelog.noarch : Yum plugin for viewing package changelogs before/after updating
yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch : Yum plugin which chooses fastest repository from a mirrorlist
yum-plugin-upgrade-helper.noarch : Yum plugin to help upgrades to the next distribution version
yum-plugin-local.noarch : Yum plugin to automatically manage a local repo. of downloaded packages
yum-plugin-merge-conf.noarch : Yum plugin to merge configuration changes when installing packages
yum-plugin-fs-snapshot.noarch : Yum plugin to automatically snapshot your filesystems during updates
fusioninventory-agent-yum-plugin.noarch : Ask FusionInventory agent to send an inventory when yum exits
yum-plugin-rpm-warm-cache.noarch : Yum plugin to access the rpmdb files early to warm up access to the db
yum-plugin-post-transaction-actions.noarch : Yum plugin to run arbitrary commands when certain pkgs are acted on
yum-NetworkManager-dispatcher.noarch : NetworkManager script which tells yum to check its cache on network change
yum-plugin-auto-update-debug-info.noarch : Yum plugin to enable automatic updates to installed debuginfo packages
yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves.noarch : Yum plugin to remove dependencies which are no longer used because of a removal
yum-cron.noarch : RPM package installer/updater/manager cron service
yum-updatesd.noarch : Update notification daemon
yum-plugin-priorities.noarch : plugin to give priorities to packages from different repos
mysql-community-release.noarch : MySQL repository configuration for yum
system-config-repo.noarch : Administrate a single yum repository file
mash.noarch : Koji buildsystem to yum repository converter
percona-release.noarch : Package to install Percona GPG key and YUM repo
grinder.noarch : A tool for synchronizing content from yum repositories
repoview.noarch : Creates a set of static HTML pages in a yum repository
fedrepos.noarch : Update fedora yum repositories on a host to use a single source
fedora-upgrade.noarch : Upgrade Fedora to next version using yum upgrade (unofficial tool)
dnf.noarch : Package manager forked from Yum, using libsolv as a dependency resolver
```

And the result of `dnf search yum-plugin` is ordered by length of package name:

```
[dr01@linuxbox ~]$ dnf search yum-plugin    
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:15:02 ago on Fri Jan  8 14:03:49 2016.
============================================================================================= N/S Matched: yum-plugin =============================================================================================
yum-plugin-ps.noarch : Yum plugin to look at processes, with respect to packages
yum-plugin-ovl.noarch : Yum plugin to work around overlayfs issues
yum-plugin-copr.noarch : Yum plugin to add copr command
yum-plugin-keys.noarch : Yum plugin to deal with signing keys
yum-plugin-local.noarch : Yum plugin to automatically manage a local repo. of downloaded packages
yum-plugin-verify.noarch : Yum plugin to add verify command, and options
yum-plugin-aliases.noarch : Yum plugin to enable aliases filters
yum-plugin-tmprepo.noarch : Yum plugin to add temporary repositories
yum-plugin-tsflags.noarch : Yum plugin to add tsflags by a commandline option
yum-plugin-changelog.noarch : Yum plugin for viewing package changelogs before/after updating
yum-plugin-list-data.noarch : Yum plugin to list aggregate package data
yum-plugin-merge-conf.noarch : Yum plugin to merge configuration changes when installing packages
yum-plugin-priorities.noarch : plugin to give priorities to packages from different repos
yum-plugin-filter-data.noarch : Yum plugin to list filter based on package data
yum-plugin-fs-snapshot.noarch : Yum plugin to automatically snapshot your filesystems during updates
yum-plugin-protectbase.noarch : Yum plugin to protect packages from certain repositories.
yum-plugin-show-leaves.noarch : Yum plugin which shows newly installed leaf packages
yum-plugin-versionlock.noarch : Yum plugin to lock specified packages from being updated
yum-plugin-puppetverify.noarch : Yum plugin to add puppet checksums to verify data
yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch : Yum plugin which chooses fastest repository from a mirrorlist
yum-plugin-rpm-warm-cache.noarch : Yum plugin to access the rpmdb files early to warm up access to the db
yum-plugin-upgrade-helper.noarch : Yum plugin to help upgrades to the next distribution version
yum-plugin-refresh-updatesd.noarch : Tell yum-updatesd to check for updates when yum exits
yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves.noarch : Yum plugin to remove dependencies which are no longer used because of a removal
fusioninventory-agent-yum-plugin.noarch : Ask FusionInventory agent to send an inventory when yum exits
yum-plugin-auto-update-debug-info.noarch : Yum plugin to enable automatic updates to installed debuginfo packages
yum-plugin-post-transaction-actions.noarch : Yum plugin to run arbitrary commands when certain pkgs are acted on
```

What could be the reason of this funny glitch?

Comment: More relevant/important packages get shorter names; add-ons, plugins, libraries split out get "basename-piece" names, which are longer;...

Comment: I'll make an answer later. Briefly: `dnf` sorts by the several criteria. One is the "weight", which is a weighted sum of all the matches of the search term with the packages' attributes such as name and description. (a name match is worth more). Another is "distance", which is len(packageattribute)-len(search term). In most of your first example, `yum` matches both the package name and description, so the sum of those two distances determines the sort order. In most of the second example, `yum-plugin` matches only the package names, so that's the only distance used to determine the sort order.